# Fastest way to match corpus of words with multiple regexes

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, optimization, list-comprehension

I want to match every word in a large corpus against multiple different regexes. Here was my first attempt. Here, word_list is the list of all english words (I am running only against the first 1000 words in these tests):

```
%%time
mapping = {f'{k1}{k2}':[] for k1 in string.ascii_lowercase for k2 in string.ascii_lowercase}

for word in word_list[:1000]:
    for let1,let2 in mapping:
        if re.search(rf'.*{let1}.*{let2}.*', word):
            mapping[let1+let2].append(word)
```

With an output of `Wall time: 22.2 s`.

Next I enveloping everything into a comprehension, such as so:

%%time

```
mapping = {f'{k1}{k2}':
                [word for word in word_list[:1000] if re.search(rf'.*{k1}.*{k2}.*', word)] 
          for k1,k2 in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase)}
```

With an improved time: `Wall time: 608 ms`.

My question is, is there any way to go even faster? Is there a way to search efficiently across an entire list, rather than going one word at a time? Any input is appreciated, really want to optimize this guy as much as possible.

To reproduce the code above, please add this code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words
word_list = words.words()
```

Comment: Shouldn't your double for loop (1st example) be `mapping[let1+let2].append(word)` rather than `mapping[let1+let2] = word`?

Comment: The `if re.search(rf'.*{let1}.*{let2}.*', word)` is not efficient enough. `if re.search(rf'{let1}.*?{let2}', word)` would be enouh, but since the `let2` is a single letter, you can even speed it up with `if re.search(rf'{let1}[^{let2}]*{let2}', word)`

Answer (score 2):

This seems ~100 times faster than your faster way:

```
mapping = {f'{k1}{k2}':[] for k1 in string.ascii_lowercase for k2 in string.ascii_lowercase}

for word in word_list[:1000]:
    chars = (c for c in word if c in string.ascii_lowercase)
    for c1, c2 in set(itertools.combinations(chars, 2)):
        mapping[c1 + c2].append(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems sqlite3 scales much better.

```py
# Implementation in the question
import re
import itertools
def func2(words):
  mapping = {f'{k1}{k2}':
                  [word for word in words if re.search(rf'.*{k1}.*{k2}.*', word)] 
            for k1,k2 in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase)}
  return mapping
```

```py
# Implementation using sqlite3
import sqlite3
def func3(words):
  with sqlite3.connect("test2.db") as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS words")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE words (word TEXT)")
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO words VALUES (?)", [(w,) for w in words])

    c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS keywords")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE keywords (keyword TEXT, key TEXT)")
    values = [(f"*{k1}*{k1}*", f"{k1}{k2}") for k1 in string.ascii_lowercase for k2 in string.ascii_lowercase]
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO keywords VALUES (?,?)", values)

    conn.create_function("matched", 2, matched, deterministic=True)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""
    SELECT
      k.key, w.word
    FROM
      words AS w
      INNER JOIN keywords AS k ON w.word GLOB k.keyword
    """)
    mapping = {f'{k1}{k2}':[] for k1 in string.ascii_lowercase for k2 in string.ascii_lowercase}
    for key, word in c:
      mapping[key].append(word)
    return mapping
```

Here is a comparison

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

out = []
for i in [100, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 15000, 20000]:
  print(f"Now at {i}")
  for j, func in zip([2,3], [func2, func3]):
    t1 = datetime.now()
    func(word_list[:i])
    t2 = datetime.now()
    out.append([i, j, (t2-t1).total_seconds()])
out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=["length", "function", "time"])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
sns.lineplot(data=out, x="length", y="time", hue="function", ax=ax)
```

[image]

Edit: But Kelly Bundy's solution is about ten times as fast.
[image]